# Setting activeFocus by clicking anywhere within an Item

Tags: qt, focus, qml, qt-quick

I want to set the activeFocus for a FocusScope by clicking anywhere within an Item.
Is there a way to achieve this without having a MouseArea over the entire Item? Because it would have to overlay all elements within the Item, making them unclickable.

I'm pretty new to QtQuick/QML and have troubles understanding how to properly implement FocusScopes. I've read about propagating click signals, but couldn't get it to work.

Assuming I have something like this (no FocusScopes for readability):

```
Rectangle
{
    id: outerRectangle

    width: 1000
    height: 1000

    // various controls in here

    Rectangle
    {
        id: innerRectangle

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        width: 200
        height: 200

        // even more controls in here
    }
}
```

I want the outerRectangle to get the activeFocus when I click anywhere on the outerRectangle and vice-versa for the innerRectangle. But all controls on both Rectangles still have to work properly.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `MouseArea` can be set to a different `z` level so that it does not overlay other controls. Apart from that I don't know if you already [read this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html) but it could be of interest. Also take in account [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-keyinteraction-example.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: Setting the Z doesn't help, sadly. As soon as the MouseArea is below another control, it won't register the click anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your `Item` with `FocusScope`:

```
FocusScope {
   Item {
       focus: true
   }
}
```

See [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#focus-prop)